# For each loop not reading the first row in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, foreach

I have a foreach loop not reading the first row in the grid view. When I do a debug, It gives me the department names and responseCount starting from the second row in the GridView.

Basically, the department names fetched from the gridview row is to be passed as a paramenter into the function getDepartmentResponseCount.ResponseCount(deptName) which returns the count for the that dedpartment.

The foreach Loop is not reading from the first row in the gridview. Below is the source code.

```
protected void gvDepartments_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Empty the string variable
    myDeptResponseCount = "";
    // Iterate though the gridView to get Dept names and response count values

    foreach (GridViewRow dept in gvDepartments.Rows)
    {
        // the actual way to get your row index            
        int rowIndex = dept.RowIndex;

        //Label respCount = dept.FindControl("lblResponses"+ dID) as Label;
        Label lblResponses = (Label)gvDepartments.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("lblResponses" + dID);

        deptName = e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();            

        // get the responseCount for each of the departments
        myDeptResponseCount = getDepartmentResponseCount.ResponseCount(deptName);

        //lblResponses.Text = myResponseCount;
        deptCount.Add(deptName);
    }

    //dID++;
    deptNameCount.Add(deptName);        
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure, that gvDepartments.Rows contains every of your rows?

Comment: Could it be that the problem arises because you set `deptName` to `e.Row.Cells...` instead of the currently indexed row's cell?

Comment: Yes it does...I personally debugged it and went through each of the lines of code...It is not giveing value for the very first row. It starts from the second row to the end. Why would that be so?

Comment: I don't really understand why you don't use the loop variable to access the values, anyway. Why use another `rowIndex` variable to do so?

Comment: The gvDepartments_RowDataBound is called for every row. Then what is the logic behind this foreach loop?

Comment: Thosten Dittmar:
deptName = e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString(); reads the department column of the gridview. So It couldn't be.

Comment: Could it be that `RowIndex` property starts at 1? Because that would 'skip' the first because c# is zero-based.

Comment: Silvermind: The row index property starts at zero.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2145607/naveen: The logic behind the foreach loop is to get the department names...pass them into a function to get the response count for that department.

Comment: If you want to loop through same grid why you are using RowDataBound? I think you have to switch to DataBound event which is called after finishing the binding. Or else you have to do it like answer below mentioned by pravprab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
protected void gvDepartments_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Empty the string variable
    myDeptResponseCount = "";
    // Iterate though the gridView to get Dept names and response count values

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // the actual way to get your row index            
        int rowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;

        //Label respCount = dept.FindControl("lblResponses"+ dID) as Label;
        Label lblResponses = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblResponses" + dID);

        deptName = e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();

        // get the responseCount for each of the departments
        myDeptResponseCount = getDepartmentResponseCount.ResponseCount(deptName);

        //lblResponses.Text = myResponseCount;
        deptCount.Add(deptName);
    }

    //dID++;
    deptNameCount.Add(deptName);
}
```